# I need to do a mobile redirect in lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd

I have this rewrite code in my htaccess file, but I need to translate it to lighttpd.

The following is the htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)noredirect=true(&|$)
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:%{HTTP_HOST},S]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
# (You could add another [OR] to the second one and add in what you
#  had to check, but I believe most mobile devices should send at
#  least one of these headers)
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/m/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xml/.*$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text/vnd.wap.wml|application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC] #*SEE NOTE BELOW

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\smredir=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/m%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I've tried rewriting the code. It seems to put me in a permanent redirect on desktop and is unaffected on mobile.

Here's the lighttpd code so far:

```
server.modules += ("mod_redirect")

$HTTP["url"] !~ "^/xml/.*$" {
    $HTTP["url"] !~ "^/m/.*$" {
        $HTTP["useragent"] =~ "(acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-|dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-|maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv|palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany|sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo|teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi|wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-|up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp|symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp)" {
            $HTTP["useragent"] !~ "macintosh" {
                $HTTP["host"] =~ "(.*)" {
                    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://%1/m/$1" )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code on my server.

Hope it helps you!

```
##  normal version of site
$HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
     $HTTP["useragent"] =~ "(Android|iPhone|Palm|BlackBerry)" {
          url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://m.example.com/$1" )
     }
}
## mobile version of site
$HTTP["host"] == "m.example.com" {
     $HTTP["useragent"] !~ "(Android|iPhone|Palm|BlackBerry)" {
          url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://example.com/$1" )
     }
}
```